# Binding an ObservableCollection of two related entities to one DataGrid

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datagrid, observablecollection

I have two related entities in my Model file.

They look like:

```
      MasterPartNumber (parent, one) --> MasterPartsList (children, many)
      (PK) partNum                        (PK) listID
           partNumDesc                    (FK) partNum
                                               parentAssyPartNum
```

If I can only bind the ItemsSource of my DataGrid to one `ObservableCollection`,
how can I include all the information from these two related entities in my DataGrid?

Note: I do not bind to `collectionViews`, only relying on `PropertyChanged` notifications and setting "SelectedItem" to a property on my viewmodel. I realize I would most likely need to cast one of the entity types to the other in order to combine them under one collection.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minutes after posting this, I realized everything was already properly set up and I just had a typo on the xaml binding for the Included (/related) tables property:

My viewmodel relevant code is below:

```
  public ObservableCollection<MasterPartNumber> AssyPns
    {
        get
        {
                var enumerable = this._context.MasterPartNumbers.Include("MasterPartsLists").Where(t => t.MasterPartsLists.Any(x => x.isAssy == true));




                return this._assyPns = new ObservableCollection<MasterPartNumber>(enumerable);



        }

        set 
        {
            this._assyPns = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AssyPns");

        }
    }

            public MasterPartNumber SelectedTopLevelAssyPN //<-- this is the selected Parent item i am getting my DataGrid's ObservableCollection from
    {
        get { return this._selectedTopLevelAssyPN; }
        set
        {
            this._selectedTopLevelAssyPN = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTopLevelAssyPN");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedAssyBOMLineItems");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList> SelectedAssyBOMLineItems //<-- this is my itemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._selectedTopLevelAssyPN != null)
            {
                var children = _context.MasterPartsLists.Where(lineItem => lineItem.parentAssyPN != null)
                                                        .Where(lineItem => lineItem.parentAssyPN == this._selectedTopLevelAssyPN.pn);     


                return this._selectedAssyBOMLineItems = new ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList>(children);


            }

            return this._selectedAssyBOMLineItems;
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedAssyBOMLineItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedAssyBOMLineItems");
        }
    }
```

The path I bound my dataGrid TextColumn to was just

```
 {Binding MasterPartNumber.pnDesc}
```

Thank you both for responding so promptly.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier if you actually bind to your parents list as the `DataContext` of your `DataGrid`, and then in the data template for each child you bind the `DataContext` to the child item.

Then you have the information wherever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your can create a partial class of your `MasterPartsList` Entity and access your sub entity detail.

```
public partial class MasterPartsList
{
    public string PartDescription
    {
        get { return this.MasterPartNumber.partNumDesc; }
    }
}
```